# Woocommerce create order from form outside of woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I have a need to create an advanced product with various discounts and conditional statements.  I have tried several plugins including Gravity Forms Product Add Ons and various others but they dont seem to do what I need them to.

My need is I want to have a form the user fills out and I can handle all conditionals and when they hit the Add to cart button it will add their order to cart.  I could use [create order](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_api_productscreate_product/) but not sure because it needs a product ID and I am kind of creating the product on the fly for each customer.  I could also [create the product as this thread suggests](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120055/woocommerce-create-new-product-and-add-to-cart-on-form-submit) then add to cart but I fear if I manually create a product for each customer that we will have an absurd amount of products.

What would be the best way to create a form and then once filled out and submitted the total and details are sent to cart?

[This link](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order/) was a good resource but doesnt go into detail about the product id or how to do the form.  Any guidance on the best way to tackle this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a wireframe of what I want to do demonstrating the dynamic text boxes and discount rules.  The deposits I am using the Woocommerce Deposits plugin. Just not sure the best way to do this.
[image]

Comment: "they don't seem to do what I need them to do" - Why not? Gravity Forms product addons (and similarly [ninja forms product addons](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-ninjaforms-product-addons/)) both allow a customer to customize a product and have that customized product added to the cart. That is very different from creating an order. So you need to clarify more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @helgatheviking I actually have read your answer which is pretty close on wordpress stackexchange, I wish I could find the link again.  In a nutshell I have this https://jsfiddle.net/96L98qpo/ - (grouped product) When a user fills out the text inputs I would like to save that data to the order; then calculate various discounts based on the quantity of each session.  I have proceeded to tackle this but since most things I find have an answer from you I would appreciate you taking a look at the updated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950114/how-to-add-woocommerce-custom-order-data

Comment: @helgatheviking here is the link I was referring to: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120055/woocommerce-create-new-product-and-add-to-cart-on-form-submit  similar setup.  I am currently using a group product but feel like if I created a form myself I could have more control over it with discounts and such then just send the info to cart using add_to_cart hook.    Im uploading an image of a wireframe so you can see my struggle :)  There will be various discounts applied and inputs.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this